# How to store values of UICollectionViewCell against each section in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

So I have did some RnD regarding this already and didn't found anything that will help me to solve this one. So the problem is consider and **paper pattern of MCQ question paper** and I want to store the each question's answer and at end I need to convert it into JSON data to post it to server. **So here all sections are my questions and all rows are my respective answers**. For now I've rendered UI and now I'm just concerned about how I can store this data against each question. Also suffering from common problem of repeating dequeue cells. So request to anyone who can guide me in correct way.

Comment: Can any one please help?

Answer (score 0):

So storing each selected index of UICollectionView in [[IndexPath]] array solved this problem for me. Where I initialized this array on view didLoad as per the count of my dataSource array. So my multi-dimensional arrays's outer loop will hold an section per count and inner loop will hold an row count. e.g. `[[1,0],[1,2],[3,4],[4,1]]` .